# replace view in activitygroup with slide in animation in android

Tags: android

I am having following code :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnSrch){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchByCode.class);
        View view = SearchGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager()
            .startActivity("SearchByCode",i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();

             SearchGroup.group.replaceView(view);

    }
}
```

But when I am clicking the button it shows the next screen abruptly. I want to show the slide-in animation here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell but I think you want to know how to launch another activity called `SearchByCode` from your current activity.

To do this you need to create an Intent object, optionally add flags or bundles to the intent, then call `startActivity(Intent)`.

Here is a code sample:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchByCode.class)
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(i);
```